# Recover corrupted photos from sd card

Tags: sd-card

I copied all my photos on a fake sd card I bought on the internet. Now my photos are almost all greyed out. Is it possible to recover them or at leat recover the thumbnails since they are not greyed out?

Comment: If you didn't use Cut or Move to put the images on your SD card: format it and get a refund, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

Many fake SD cards on the Internet are usually a low-capacity card (for example, 8GB) with modified firmware to say something much higher (like 512GB). When it reaches the actual storage capacity, it always overwrites old data (by repeatedly writing to the last few MB of actual capacity) or stops recording new data.

Because of that, when you exceed the real capacity of the SD card, you risk losing data unrecoverably - even recovery programs like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) can't recover them.

You can still see the thumbnails correctly because your computer or phone cached the thumbnails before you copied the images.

If you only copied the images (didn't move or cut them), your photos are fine. If you moved (or cut) the images, try:

- Moving all the images that aren't corrupt off of the SD card.
- Take screenshots of the thumbnails of the ones that became corrupt (it is a very long and tedious process (and the resulting images will have a much lower resolution compared to the originals) but can recover the images.

Comment: Hope my edit doesn't conflict!