# WhatsApp photos getting corrupted after transferring/copying them from original location to external SD card

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-grand

My WhatsApp media (photos and videos) gets corrupted when I move and copy them from their default location to the external SD card. The photos and videos behave properly for some time before becoming greyed out and unrecoverable. Moreover, it is very puzzling to me that this does not happen with all of the transferred/copied WhatsApp media. While majority of the files get corrupted and unusable, some of the files are good. I have no idea why this is happening. Could anyone shed more light on this issue? I have a Galaxy Grand Prime +.

**EDIT 1:**

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203006/333809) looked useful but it claims a faulty SD card to be the cause. Moreover, my issues seem to be occurring only with WhatsApp media.

**EDIT 2:**

I took photos from my camera and put them in my SD card and even those photos got corrupted. **So the problem is not confined to WhatsApp.**

Comment: Are the files good before you copy them ? How do you copy them? If the files get corrupted when you copy them have you tried to use a different way to copy them?

Comment: @Robert Yes the files are good before I copy them. I select the file while it is in its original location (WhatsApp folder) and move them to the SD card. _...have you tried to use a different way to copy them?_ Yes. At first, I was simply _moving_ them to the SD card folder. When I was having no luck with preserving the files, I  _copied_ them to the SD card and then deleted them in the original WhatsApp folder. This also did not save my files from getting corrupted.

Comment: Please also answer may question how you copy/move the files. Do you use an app, or through a computer connected via USB? If the sd-card is not the problem then the problem must be the way you use for the file operations.

Comment: I do not use an app or a USB. The SD card is in my phone. All I do is select the file I want, click on "Move to Album" and then click on the album I created in my SD card. The file then gets transferred to my SD card's album.

Comment: @Robert I put photos I took with my camera in my SD card and even those got corrupted. So could the problem be with my SD card?

Comment: Most likely yes. In this case the sd-card may be corrupt, partial defect or it may be a fake.

Comment: @Robert How can I fully confirm that the defect is in the SD card itself?

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-check-an-sd-card-for-errorshttps://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-check-an-sd-card-for-errors

Comment: @Aayush Thank you for the response but the link is not working.

Comment: sorry i pasted the link twice.. here u go : ) https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-check-an-sd-card-for-errors